# getting column means for non zero data

Tags: r

Can R get the colMeans for the non-zero values of a data frame?

```
data<-data.frame(col1=c(1,0,1,0,3,3),col2=c(5,0,5,0,7,7))
colMeans(data)   # 1.33,4
```

I would like something like:

```
mean(data$col1[data$col1>0]) # 2
mean(data$col2[data$col2>0]) # 6
```

Thanks in advance: D

---

Benchmarks of Solutions:

```
n <- 2E4
m <- 1E3
data <- matrix(runif(n*m),nrow = n)

system.time (col_means <- colSums(data)/colSums(!!data) ) 
#   user  system elapsed 
# 0.087   0.007   0.094 

system.time (   colMeans(NA^(data==0)*data, na.rm=TRUE)) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.167   0.084   0.251 

system.time (vapply(data, function(x) mean(x[x!=0]), numeric(1))) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#126.519   0.737 127.715 

library(dplyr)
system.time (summarise_each(data, funs(mean(.[.!=0])))) # Gave error
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change the `0` to `NA` and then use `colMeans` as it has an option for `na.rm=TRUE`.  In a two step process, we convert the data elements that are '0' to 'NA', and then get the `colMeans` excluding the `NA` elements.

```
  is.na(data) <- data==0
  colMeans(data, na.rm=TRUE) 
  #   col1 col2 
  #    2    6
```

If you need that in a single step, we can change the logical matrix  (`data==0`) to `NA` and 1 by doing (`NA^`) for values corresponding to '0' and non-zero elements and then multiply with original data so that 1 value change to the element in that position and NA remains as such.  We can do `colMeans` on that output as above.

```
   colMeans(NA^(data==0)*data, na.rm=TRUE)
   #  col1 col2 
   #   2    6
```

Another option is using `sapply/vapply`.  If the dataset is really big, converting to a `matrix` may not be a good idea as it may cause issues with memory.  By looping through the columns either with `sapply` or a more specific `vapply` (would be a bit more fast), we get the `mean` of the non-zero elements.

```
 vapply(data, function(x) mean(x[x!=0]), numeric(1))
 #  col1 col2 
 #  2    6
```

Or we can use `summarise_each` and specify the function inside the `funs` after subsetting the non-zero elements.

```
 library(dplyr)
 summarise_each(data, funs(mean(.[.!=0])))
 #  col1 col2
 #1    2    6
```

Comment: this is what I currently do.  I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: @user3294343  In your post, the `sapply/vapply` part was not mentioned.  So, I didn't know about it.

Comment: How does the NA ^ (data==0) work?  nevermind... i get it .  (did not refresh). Really smart!

Answer (score 12):

You can use `colSums` on both the data and it's "logical representation" to divide the column sums by the number of non-zero elements for each column:

```
colSums(data)/colSums(!!data)
col1 col2 
   2    6
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.

Comment: What is the double !! doing?

Comment: @HermanToothrot Logical "not" twice. The end result is the same as `as.logical` on each element.