# How to compute mean of non zero elements of each row in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, rows, mean

I would like to compute mean for non-zero elements for each row. Below is a an example data set

```
data=data.frame(x1=c(8,0,9),x2=c(0,0,10),x3=c(16,10,2))
data
x1  x2  x3
8   0   16
0   0   10
9   10  2
```

The desired outcome will be

```
mean
12
10
 7
```

Thank you.

Not:[getting column means for non zero data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790936/getting-column-means-for-non-zero-data)

I did try but it is not working since when I convert to NA value the mean will be NA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We `replace` the '0' with `NA` and make use of the `na.rm` parameter from `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(replace(data, data == 0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 12 10  7
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a simple solution:

```
apply(data,1,function(x) mean(x[x!=0]))
```